# how to print in my local or network printer using php, when the webserver is out of my local network?

Tags: php, networking, printing, local

I have tested various commands, but none with positive feedback for what I need. To print on the same network as the web server, it is easy to use commands like shell_exec (), exec (), printer_open () ... Not my case.
I need to print directly to my USB printer, and to a shared printer on my local network; Not on the WebServer or on a printer on the WebServer network. How to proceed?
I use php, apache, a cloud web server. My local network is my PC with a printer and my notebook with another printer, both shared and working normally with each other.

I try this:

```
$printer = "myprinter";
if($ph = printer_open( $printer ) )
{
 printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW");
 printer_write($ph,"Text to print");
 printer_close($ph);
}
```

---

And this:

```
$impressora = "\\\\10.1.1.50\deskjet";
$handle = printer_open($impressora);
if (!$handle) die("Printer not found!");

echo $handle;
echo "<p>".printer_get_option($handle, PRINTER_DEVICENAME)."</p>";
echo "<p>".printer_get_option($handle, PRINTER_DRIVERVERSION)."</p>";
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "TEXT");
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_PAPER_FORMAT, PRINTER_FORMAT_A4);
printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_TEXT_ALIGN, PRINTER_TA_CENTER);
printer_write($handle, "TESTE");
printer_close($handle);
```

---

And this:

```
exec('copy c:\textfile.txt localprinter');
shell_exec('copy c:\textfile.txt \\\\\10.1.1.50\deskjet');
```

*it works by prompt in my local pc.

Thank you.

Comment: Hallo and Welcome to Stackoverflow. You should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You'll realize that your question is against our rules. We're here to help you with specific programming problems, means that you have to provide us code and show us what you've tried so far. We're really looking forward to help you with programming, but we're not here for those kind of problems... at least not how you asked it.

Comment: Hi, tks. Post updated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but what I understand is you are trying to print from a webserver to a USB Printer and a Network Printer.

You can check this answer that suggest port forwarding for Network Printer: [Print to local network printer using port forwarding.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66005927/15071490)

To do the same for a USB printer, you'll need to connect your printer to your routers USB port and if your router don't have a USB port then you'll need to get a mini print server device.